# Can log4j and java util logging coexist

Tags: java.util.logging, log4j

My application uses log4j but OkHttpClient uses java util logging. So apart from log4j.properties, I created a logging.properties file with the following contents:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler

.level=FINE

okhttp3.internal.http2.level=FINE

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = logs/%hjava%u.log

java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000

java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1

java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I then added this to jvm params used for starting the application `-Djava.util.logging.config.file="file://${BASE_DIR}/logging.properties"`

But I don't see any new folders being created as indicated by the Filehandler. Any one know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't see any new folders being created as indicated by the Filehandler. Any one know why?

The FileHandler will not create any [new folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732247/how-to-create-directories-for-logger-files-through-filehandler/22796633#22796633).  A directory must be created before the FileHandler will create a file.

The system property requires a path to file that is located on the filesystem It will not expand system properties or environment variables by using the dollar sign syntax.

You can use a relative path based off of the working directory or you have to use an absolute path to the logging.properties.  The logging properties can not be packaged inside of an archive.

If you want to work around this limitation then you want to create [a custom config class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) and use the `java.util.logging.config.class` property in conjunction with the `java.util.logging.config.file` property.  You then write a class that reads the `file://${BASE_DIR}/logging.properties` and performs the needed transformation into a path to a file.  Then [update the configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration-java.io.InputStream-java.util.function.Function-) if you are using JDK9 or newer.  On older versions you need to use [readConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration-java.io.InputStream-) and add code to work [work around limitations of the LogManager](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033661)